# How access class variables in c++

Tags: c++, class, variables

Is it possible in c++ to access class variables in other classes without creating an object. I have tried to use static, but the other class doesnt recognize my variable.
I have 3 classes. In two of those the sae variables should be used. In the third class I am changing the values. Would be grateful if you could help. Maybe youve got an example.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Perhaps post some example code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class Myclass
{

    public:
         static int i;
};

int Myclass::i = 10;


class YourClass
{

    public:
        void doSomething()
        {
             Myclass::i = 10;  //This is how you access static member variables
        }

};

int main()
{
    YourClass obj;
    obj.doSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can i create a class variable without using `static` keyword?

Answer (score 5):

`static` is the right keyword here:

```
class A {
public:
  static int i; // <-- this is a class variable
};

class B {
public:
  void f() { A::i = 3; } // <-- this is how you access class variables
};
```

They only potential problem I can think of is that

1. You made the class variable `protected` or `private`, thus rendering it inaccessible from other code.
2. You forgot to specify the full scope of the class variable (with `A::` in this example).

Comment: THANK YOU. I would have accepted your answer too, but i had to decide.

Comment: @frerichraabe can i create a class variable without using `static` keyword?

Answer (score 0):

I think the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) would help, but I'm no big fan of it.  A lot better design would be to have one class take ownership of the object, and pass references to this object to the other classes.

Answer (score -1):

**yes you can bro, try this**

struct car{

```
        string model;
        string paint;
        int price;


           };


         int main(){

          // creates an object of the class car

            car BMW;

          // assign the values
           bmw.model = "m sports";
            bmw.paint ="red";
            bmw.price = 24000;


              }
```

Comment: OP wanted to do it *"without creating an object"*.

Comment: Best answer ever!